# PostgreSQL + Spring Boot JPA computed property mapping in repository native queries

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, postgis

I'm currently writing the code for a geolocation app (so I'm using PostGIS). My query currently sorts results by distance to the user, and I want to return the distance in meters for every result.

My repository code looks as follows (note that I'm doing keyset pagination, hence the WHERE condition):

```java
@Query(value = "WITH distance_query AS (" +
        "   SELECT p.*, ST_Distance(p.location, ST_MakePoint(:lng, :lat)) AS distance_in_m " +
        "   FROM places p" +
        ") " +
        "SELECT * FROM distance_query " +
        "WHERE distance_in_m > :lastDistanceInM " +
        "ORDER BY distance_in_m ASC", nativeQuery = true)
List<PlaceDto> findNearbyPlaces(
        double lat,
        double lng,
        double lastDistanceInM
);
```

My entity contains a `@Transient` field `Double distanceInM`, but the distance_in_m from the query is not getting mapped to this field. My understanding is this is expected because `@Transient` is meant to be used to completely ignore the annotated fields when mapping.

I've seen potential approaches involve using `@Formula`, but because the `lat` and `lng` values are variable I don't think that would work. I would also like to avoid recomputing the distance (hence the usage of a CTE in my original query).

Is there any way I can get the `distanceInM` field to be populated with the computed value?

Right now the query is working just fine, the only problem is the `distanceInM` property not getting populated.

EDIT:

The `PlaceDto` currently looks like this:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "places")
public class PlaceDto {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private String id;

    private Date updateDate;
    private String name;
    public Point location;
    private String address;

    @Transient
    public Double distanceInM;

    public PlaceDto() {
    }

    // Getters
}
```

Comment: can you also share `PlaceDto` because here in case with native query you should use Interface Base DTO ? I can help you with it just add `PlaceDto`

Comment: @AndreiLisa thanks for the reply! I just added it

Comment: Hey I added an answer, can you check  ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your query and entity class, next one solution can meet your requirements and also solve the problem with extract all dates.

First of all:

Create a Interface Projection that match your fields names in `AS` clause in native query:

```
public interface PlaceDtoInterfaceProjection {

  String getId();

  Date getUpdateDate();

  String getName();

  Point getLocation();

  String getAddress();

  Double getDistanceInM();

}
```

Second one change a little bit the query in repository:

```
  @Query(value = "WITH distance_query AS (" +
      "   SELECT p.id AS id, p.update_date AS updateDate, p.name AS name,"
      + " p.location AS location, p.address AS address,"
      + " ST_Distance(p.location, ST_MakePoint(:lng, :lat)) AS distanceInM " +
      "   FROM places p" +
      ") " +
      "SELECT * FROM distance_query " +
      "WHERE distanceInM > :lastDistanceInM " +
      "ORDER BY distanceInM ASC", nativeQuery = true)
  List<PlaceDtoInterfaceProjection> findNearbyPlaces(
      @Param("lat") double lat,
      @Param("lng") double lng,
      @Param("lastDistanceInM") double lastDistanceInM
  );
```

It is going to work well but i am not so sure about `Point` by the way it is simplest way to do it more details or alternative way how you can extract it you can find [spring-data-jpa-dto-native-queries](https://thorben-janssen.com/spring-data-jpa-dto-native-queries/)

P.S. About `Point` you can extract separately `x` and `y` from database and then construct it but I think you know how to do it in your own.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

This seems to work, but when trying to use the results I'm getting `class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class ...PlaceInterface ([Ljava.lang.Object; is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; ...PlaceInterface is in unnamed module of loader 'app')`. It looks like the results are `Object[]`. Do you know what I can do about this?

Comment: can you show how you are using `findNearbyPlaces` in service layer ? Because in this case with Interface Projection you should have something like this: `List<PlaceDtoInterfaceProjection> result = repo.findNearbyPlaces(...)` and that is all.

Comment: Looks something like `repo.findNearbyPlaces(...).stream().map(place -> PlaceModel.mapFrom(place)).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: i think now in this case you should use `convertor` to map to another object.

Comment: Do you have an example of how that would look?

Comment: yep right [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/validation/convert.html), there is about String to Integer, but you will have to do PlaceDtoInterfaceProjection to PlaceModel and that is all

Comment: But when debugging the actual objects seem to be of type `Object[]` and not `PlaceDtoInterfaceProjection` (that's why I cannot do something like `repo.nearbyPlaces(...).get(0).getName()`. How would the converter work?

Comment: You can do it with convertors without any problems just have a look [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections), I mean after fetching data with projection you can get fields separately and set to another object

Comment: But I'm getting the exception I referenced in my first message when trying to access any of the fields (like `.getName()`, for instance)... I'm not sure how I could write a convertor if I can't fetch the fields individually without getting the exception

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255692/discussion-between-blastervla-and-andrei-lisa).